# Distribution metrics for pubsub's subscription acked time

Tags: monitoring, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there something like a distribution metrics for pub/sub subscription to tell me what is the p99, p95 of acked messages?

For example: 99% of messsages are acked under 500ms

Comment: just curious, which language are you using?

Comment: we are using golang

Comment: @TravisWebb Google recently gives us pubsub subscription Ack_latencies which is exactly this. It's still in beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub does not export an ack latency distribution Stackdriver metric. The closest related metrics are `subscription/num_undelivered_messages`, `subscription/oldest_unacked_message_age`, and `subscription/pull_ack_message_operation_count`. (Source: [Pub/Sub monitoring guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring))

If you happen to be using the Go client library, there is OpenCensus integration on SendAcks, which could give you the distribution you're interested in: https://godoc.org/gocloud.dev/pubsub#hdr-OpenCensus_Integration

Otherwise, you'll have to instrument and measure this yourself in your subscriber code.

Answer (score 0):

Google finally give us this metric called ack_latency for subscriber. It's still in beta